# Conditional decorator

Tags: python, conditional-statements, decorator, python-decorators

My function break rule 'DRY'. That's why I wanna make decorator to solve this problem. For example

```
def change_status(state: str) -> None:
    print(f"change {state} to pending")

    try:
        ...
        print(f"change{state} to success")
    except BaseException:
        print(f"change {state} to error")
```

As you can see that print() could call max and min 2 times. And I want to make  decorator like

```
 def decorator():
        def wrapper(func):
            print(f"change{state} to pending")
            return func()
            .... # if try is success: print(f"change{state} to success")
            else:
                print(f"change {state} to error")
        return wrapper
```

I hope you can understand my question, also sorry for my English.

Comment: What is rule "DRY"? What is your decorated function supposed to do?

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong Don't repeat yourself

Comment: Why do you think you are breaking the DRY rule ?

Comment: Did you mean that you want the decorator to do all that printing? Perhaps just extract that and the `try/except` into the decorator.

Comment: Your `decorator` isn't a decorator. `decorator` should take `func` and `wrapper` should take the arguments to pass to `func`. It's not clear what should be printed if you decorate a function without a `state` argument

Comment: The easy bit is the first `print()`. See if you can write a decorator which prints something before calling the wrapped function. There must be thousands of posts here with simple decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your function to do just what you were doing inside the try block (before printing success). Then, change your decorator to:

```
def decorator(func):
     def wrapper(state):
          print(f"change {state} to pending")

          try:
              func(state)
              print(f"change {state} to success")
          except BaseException:
              print(f"change {state} to error")
     return wrapper
```

Comment: Ok, now you have working code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out :) I'm in a hurry trying to do some contribution on SO while waiting for a code to finish running at my work.

Comment: I think its best to actually try your code out before posting it. Still, you got there in the end. +1

Comment: Agree. It's because I was on my mobile phone in the bathroom of my workplace :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a decorator that will update and log the program state like this:

```
def update_state(state):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"change {state} to pending")
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
                print(f"change {state} to success")
                return result
            except:
                print(f"change {state} to error")
                raise # This ensures that you still get to see the original error
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

To use this, for example:

```
@update_state("my state")
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y
    
divide(10, 2)  # success
divide(1, 0)   # error
```

Comment: I like what you've done, but its a bit "bait and switch" by changing `state` to be a parameter of the decorator.

Comment: @quamrana then what should `state` be? Not clear from the original question, but this arrangement is the one that seems closest to a structure I would consider using. Maybe `state` would be an object that logs and tracks state instead of a string that is simply printed.

Comment: In general, if its not clear you should ask the OP for clarifications, otherwise confusion ensues. I thought it was clear that `state` should be a parameter of the original function, but then I looked at the decorator again and there is no state. So what do I know?